# "Shear" sort list of jobs for multiple threads efficiently

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, linq, sorting

I have got a `List` which contains several `Mesh`-Objects. This is how such a mesh-class looks like:

```
public class Mesh
{
    public int GridWidth { get; }
    public int GridHeight { get; }
    public List<File> Files { get; }
    /* ... */
}
```

The `List` of files inside a mesh object contains `File`-Objects that mostly consists of a string with the filesystems-path to the file and a two dimensional array which will hold the content of the file after it got parsed.

```
public class File
{
    public string Path { get; }
    public double[][] Matrix { get; set; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Multithreading and parsing works fine. I have decided to launch as many threads as my CPU has single cores. In my case: 4.

With the help of Linq I concentrate all file-object in an own List at first:

```
List<File> allFiles = meshes.SelectMany(mesh => mesh.Files).ToList();
```

After that each Thread gets 1/4 of the Objects from this list and starts parsing the files.

**And this is my problem**: Files of the same size are located inside the same mesh (`GridWidth`* `GridHeight` = Number of parsed matrix-cells). At this point it could happen by chance that one thread gets only files that have got a big size while another thread gets only files of low sizes. In this case one thread would finish earlier than the other thread(s) - and I don't want that because that would be inefficient.

So I had the idea to sort the list of meshes according to their size first and after that adding their files in orientation to the *Shear Sort Method* (or *Snake Sort*) to a new List for each thread. The following algorithm works. But I think that their could be some room of improvement.

**And these are my questions**: Is this algorithm already efficient enough or does exist a better way for providing lists of files to each thread? If there isn't a better way I would be interested in a "smarter" way of coding (the for-loop seems a little bit complex with all its if/else and modulo operations).

```
int cores = 4;
List<File>[] filesOfThreads = new List<Slice>[cores];

List<File> allFilesDesc = meshes.OrderByDescending(mesh => mesh.GridWidth * mesh.GridHeight).SelectMany(mesh => mesh.Files).ToList();

int threadIndex = 0;
/*
 * Inside this for-loop the threadIndex changes
 * with each cycle in this way (in case of 4 cores):
 * 0->1->2->3->3->2->1->0->0->1->2->3->3->2 ...
 * With each cycle a file of the current position of 
 * allFilesDesc[i] is added to the list of
 * filesOfThreads[threadIndex]. In this "shear" sort
 * way every thread should get approximately the same
 * number of big and small files.
 */
for (int i = 0; i < allFilesDesc.Count; i++)
{
    if (i < cores)
    {
        filesOfThreads[threadIndex] = new List<File>();
    }
    filesOfThreads[threadIndex].Add(allFilesDesc[i]);
    if (i < cores - 1)
    {
        threadIndex++;
    }
    else if ((i + 1) % cores != 0)
    {
        threadIndex += ((i + 1) / cores) % 2 == 0 ? 1 : -1;
    }
}

foreach (var files in filesOfThreads)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => ComputeFiles(files));
    thread.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggest

```
/// <summary>
/// Helper methods for the lists.
/// </summary>
public static class ListExtensions
{
public static List<List<T>> ChunkBy<T>(this List<T> source, int chunkSize) 
{
    return source
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList();
}
}
```

For example, if you chuck the list of 18 items by 5 items per chunk, it gives you the list of 4 sublists with the following items inside: 5-5-5-3.

Comment: Thank you! Although this code will work it won't solve my issue with sublists that probably contain unbalanced objects related to their size. In case the input of your function has been ordered by descending I think that the sum of object sizes in the first sublist is bigger than the sum of the second or third sublist. Have a look at the big comment inside my last listing to understand what I mean. Your code adds every fourth position of the input list to a corresponding chunk. With shear sort (or snake sort) a chunk contains elements from different positions.

Comment: But probably my doubts are irrelevant if I pass on ordering the list by descending first. Then your code might be a better solution.

Comment: exactly, you can pass first the list ordered how you prefer.

Comment: Thank you. I had an idea of improvement and now it seems to be perfekt: Instead of passing the `chunkSize` it's more suitable to pass the number of threads you wish to start (in this case 4) and do the following [...]`.GroupBy(x => x.Index % cores)`[...]

Comment: oh nice idea ! at last it is what you want , threads :) nice job